# Tag input not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Why isn't the tag input showing up?

```
<div ng-controller="DrawingsController">
<tags-input ng-model="tags"></tags-input>
<div class="controls">
    <label>Filter:</label>
    <button class="filter" data-filter="all">All</button>
    <button class="filter" data-filter=".name-{{name}}" ng-repeat="name in names">{{name}}</button>

</div>
<div class="test">
    <div id="MixItUpContainer1" class="container">
        <div class="mix name-{{drawing.name}}" data-myorder="{{drawing.value}}" ng-repeat="drawing in drawings">Value : {{drawing.name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The tag input works on other pages but it's not showing up on this one.

JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ce1qzjv1/

Update:

This is my updated fiddle: jsfiddle.net/og19nL11/1

I want them to show up in their own value box like the others but it's not working

Comment: You may have a syntax error somewhere on that page which prevents the tag from showing. A closing div or whatever. #wildguess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the fiddle you posted, `ngTagsInput` is not referenced. You should add it as a dependency of your application.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTagsInput']);
```

Comment: Oops, fixed it. Thanks.

Also, why aren't the tags showing up when I add them? (Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/og19nL11/2/)

@squiroid

Comment: I get a 404 error when I open that link @squiroid :(

Comment: This is mine: http://jsfiddle.net/og19nL11/1/

i want them to show up in their own value box like the others but it's not working @SergioTulentsev

Comment: I am not sure but `tags` name seems to be reserved so I used `taging` instead of that Fiddle :- http://jsfiddle.net/og19nL11/3/

Comment: @lol_PHP just remove " from the url [http://jsfiddle.net/ce1qzjv1/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/ce1qzjv1/4/) and it works :)